# Creation and positioning of dynamic buttons in as3 inside a movie clip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

HI Am NEW TO as3 , can any one help me regarding creation of dynamic buttons and assign click events, please view the attachment picture to know my requirements..

```
    http://i39.tinypic.com/9gkmds.jpg
```

Pls guide me done this functionality in as3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
   var button:SimpleButton = new MyButton(); //whatever the library linkage of your button is
   addChild(button);
   button.x = i * 100;
}
```